# Postgres BRIN index over datetime field

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a table where I insert information periodically quite often. I have a Btree
index over columns A, B, C. The size of the index is quite huge and almost 2/3 of the table. The types of the column A is boolean, column B is varchar(FK to another table) and column C is a datetime field.

I have two queries of interest. First where I use column A, B and C in the query. The second query filters over column A and C.

In both my queries I have the condition of datetime > now().

The insertions for columns A and B are all random, have no order. For column C they are also random but always future values.

After I filter by column B and C, the resulting set will only have 50 rows approximately.

My questions:

- Since after I filter by column B and C, the resulting set will only have 50 rows is it worth it have an index over column A as well.
- Can I use a BRIN index for column C even though the inserts are not in order?
- I created BRIN index over column C but when I analyze the query it doesnt use the brin index. The query looks like this `explain analyze select * from my_table where C between '2023-07-25 18:46:12.164035 +00:00' and '2024-07-25 18:46:12.164035 +00:00'`

The results show that the database is doing a sequential scan, even though I have a BRIN index created over the column C. This testing table doesnt have the a Btree index over column A, B and C.

```
Seq Scan on my_table  (cost=0.00..24574.60 rows=1012513 width=33) (actual time=0.015..60.246 rows=1013338 loops=1)
  Filter: ((C >= '2023-07-25'::date) AND (C <= '2024-07-25'::date))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 702
Planning Time: 0.070 ms
Execution Time: 79.117 ms
```

Comment: Could you please share the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) for your sql statement? (in plain text, as an update to your original question) And also share the DDL for the tables and indexes involved.

Comment: What does it mean that B is a key?

Comment: Your contention *resulting set will only have 50 rows* is not what the explain plan actually shows. It shows you retrieved over 1000K rows in less than 1 sec. If that for is the complete query then what is the issue.? BTW your where clause is effectively `C='2023-07-25'`. Just a guess but did you generate test using current_date or now()?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @jjanes , I update my question.

Comment: @Belayer You are right, but this is a test dataset. My original dataset is significantly bigger. I want to compare the performance improvements if I use one index or the other.

Answer (score 0):

> Since after I filter by column B and C, the resulting set will only have 50 rows is it worth it have an index over column A as well.

If you have to jump to 50 random places in the table only for half(?) of them to fail, that is a lot of extra random IO.  So it would probably make sense to include A into the index.  Having a stand-alone index on A probably does not.

> Can I use a BRIN index for column C even though the inserts are not in order?

You can do it, as you have seen.  But it won't be very helpful, as you have also seen.  Your experience is not an anomaly, it fits how BRIN indexes work.

Comment: Makes sense what you said regarding the database having to jump at 50 random places. Its not clear though what you mean by "Having a stand-alone index on A probably does not."

Also do you know the reasoning why the BRIN index is not working and in what situation would it work?